# Hard Drive Reformat: Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Developer' doesn't match any valid certificate/private key pair in the default keychain

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I recently had my old hard drive crash and had to reinstall everything on my mac. I've finally gotten everything working again, except for running iOS apps on my iPhone, I keep getting the error:

Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Developer' doesn't match any valid certificate/private key pair in the default keychain

I know this has something to do with the keychain, but I did it so long ago that I don't remember what the steps were (and I don't even think the steps would be the same again in this case). Any ideas how I can install my iOS apps on my phone again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your hard drive crashed, all your certificates in keychain are lost. So you can't codesign your apps with same certificate again. You need to revoke the certificate from provisioning portal, update provisioning profile from portal with this certificate then download it. Re code sign your apps with this certificate.

When you first created certificate on the mac it gets installed into keychain access. You SHOULD backup private key and cert in case of events like this.Downloading provisioning profile from portal is not the same.

Going forward to save yourself from this: go to Xcode organizer -> Library -> Developer Profile -> Export then save that profile somewhere safe. Just in case you crash your hard drive again you can import this profile to new machine and save yourself from going through certificate revocation.

Comment: Wow that was a LOT easier than the first time I had to do it. Had it up and running in 5 minutes flat. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to generate a new signing certificate. When you did this before you created a private/public key pair that were stored in your Keychain. When your hard drive crashed the private key was lost so you can no longer sign apps with the old certificate hence the need for creation of a new certificate.

Follow these steps: http://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/certificates/team/howto.action